# Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\phi^3e^{4x}-\phi^4e^{3x}-\phi^3e^{2x}+e^x+2\over (\phi e^x)^5-1}\cdot2xdx=\left({\pi\over 5}\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Prove the following equation, given that $\phi$ stands for the golden ratio:

> $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\phi^3e^{4x}-\phi^4e^{3x}-\phi^3e^{2x}+e^x+2\over (\phi e^x)^5-1}\cdot2xdx=\color{blue}{\left({\pi\over 5}\right)^2}\tag1$$

---

**What I've tried:**

> $${1\over (\phi e^x)^5-1}={1\over \phi^5e^{5x}}\cdot{1\over 1-\phi^{-5}e^{-5x}}={1\over \phi^{5(n+1)}e^{5x}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-5nx}\tag2$$

Apply $(2)$ to $(1)$

Hence

Let $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\phi^{-5(n+1)}$$

> $$I=S\int_{0}^{\infty}(\phi^3 e^{-x(5n+1)}-\phi^4 e^{-x(5n+2)}-\phi^3e^{-x(5n+3)}+e^{-x(5n+4)}+2e^{-x(5n+5)})\cdot2xdx\tag3$$

integrate $(3)$ term by term using integration by parts

Take an example from $(3)$

> $$2\phi^3\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-(5n+1)x}dx= {2\phi^3\over (5n+1)^2}$$

This method it is definitely tedious. To evaluate the sum is another lengthy method.

Anyone with a clever technique of tackling (1)? (Avoid series if possible)

Comment: (3) does not work as $\phi e^x<1$ is not true.

Comment: So, change $\frac{1}{\phi^5 e^{5x} -1} = \frac{1}{\phi^5 e^{5x} }\frac{1}{1-1/\phi^5 e^{-5x} }$. Then, do the expansions etc.

Comment: Ok thank @Vaneet, let me try that then

Comment: By factorizing the numerator and denominator one can bring the integral to the simpler form $$\frac{2}{\phi^2 \Im(\omega')}\cdot\Im\left[(\omega'-2)\int_0^\infty\frac{x\,{\rm d}x}{e^x-\omega'}\right]$$ where $\omega' = \frac{e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}}{\phi}$ To evaluate this one is lead to the same polylog-sum as given in Jack's answer.

Comment: ...but one can get around using series (as you seem to want) if one can just show that $$ \frac{2}{\phi^2 \Im(\omega')}\cdot \Im\left[\frac{\omega'-2}{\omega'}\text{Li}_2(\omega')\right] = \left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to compute:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\phi^{-2}e^{-x}-\phi^{-1}e^{-2x}-\phi^{-2}e^{-3x}-\phi^{-5}e^{-4x}+2\phi^{-5}e^{-5x}}{1-\phi^{-5}e^{-5x}}\,2x\,dx $$
hence by expanding the integrand function as a (convergent!) geometric series we get:
$$\small I = 2\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{\phi^{5k+2}(5k+1)^2}-\frac{1}{\phi^{5k+1}(5k+2)^2}-\frac{1}{\phi^{5k+2}(5k+3)^2}+\frac{1}{\phi^{5k+5}(5k+4)^2}+\frac{2}{\phi^{5k+5}(5k+5)^2}\right)$$
that is related with $\text{Li}_2$ evaluated at $\frac{1}{\phi}$. See [Landen's identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandensIdentity.html).